# Php docker phpmyadmin error php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for database failed

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin

I have setup docker for laravel + mysql+phpmyadmin  , larvel and mysql working but when try to login phpmyadmin i got below error

php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for database failed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymY3Q.png)

my docker compose file

```
version: "3"

networks:
  zervetek:


services:
  backend:
    build: .
    container_name: zervetek_back
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - zervetek
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=zerveteck
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
    networks:
      - zervetek

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=database
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
```

i tried image: phpmyadmin:latest nothing work any idea

Comment: Do you have a `network` entry for `phpmyadmin`? I don't see one in your docker compose file

Comment: yeah it;s working after put network entry, i thought that;s not a big issue and try on other things,,  thank you for the help